# Consecutive Rows to fetch from SQL server table

Tags: sql-server

We have following table structure

```
+---------+------------+-------+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| EmpCode |   InDate   | Shift | ArrTime |  OutDate   | DepTime | HoursWrkd | OverTime | Status |
+---------+------------+-------+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|     110 | 04/11/2008 | GN    | 9:45    | 04/11/2008 | 0:00    | 0:00      | 0:00     | P P    |
|     115 | 03/11/2008 | GN    | 9:44    | 03/11/2008 | 18:00   | 8:16      | 0:00     | P P    |
|     105 | 03/11/2008 | GN    | 0:00    | 03/11/2008 | 0:00    | 0:00      | 0:00     | A A    |
|     105 | 04/11/2008 | GN    | 0:00    | 03/11/2008 | 0:00    | 0:00      | 0:00     | A A    |
|     110 | 03/11/2008 | GN    | 9:45    | 03/11/2008 | 0:00    | 0:00      | 0:00     | P P    |
|      86 | 29/11/2008 | HD    | 0:00    | 29/11/2008 | 0:00    | 0:00      | 0:00     | HD     |
|     105 | 05/11/2008 | GN    | 9:45    | 04/11/2008 | 0:00    | 0:00      | 0:00     | P P    |
+---------+------------+-------+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

We want those records where Employee is continuous absent for two days. Days interval will be dynamic.
So, this above result set should return

```
+---------+------------+-------+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
| EmpCode |   InDate   | Shift | ArrTime |  OutDate   | DepTime | HoursWrkd | OverTime | Status |
+---------+------------+-------+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
|     105 | 03/11/2008 | GN    | 0:00    | 03/11/2008 | 0:00    | 0:00      | 0:00     | A A    |
|     105 | 04/11/2008 | GN    | 0:00    | 03/11/2008 | 0:00    | 0:00      | 0:00     | A A    |
+---------+------------+-------+---------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Does "Days interval will be dynamic" mean that sometimes you will want those records where an Employee has been continuously absent for 3, 4, ..., 23, ... days ? Also, could you state explicitly what your `Status` column means? Also also, could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: You need to further define your question.

Comment: Yes AakashM you are right dear. And for Status, it is like 'A A' Means Absent, 'P P' Means Present, 'HD' means Holiday and 'WO' Means weekly off. But we want only those employees who are continuously absent for 3, 4, ..., 23, ... days. i.e status Should Be 'A A'

Comment: 'P P' means present? I weep for everyone who has to query against this system. :-(

Answer (score 7):

Without knowing what you mean by dynamic days interval, the following is an example of how I might attempt this.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.ShiftStatii
(
    ShiftStatusID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_ShiftStatii 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , StatusName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.ShiftStatii (StatusName) 
VALUES ('Present'), ('Absent'), ('Holiday'); 

CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees
(
    EmpID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Employees 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , EmployeeName VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (EmployeeName) 
VALUES ('John'), ('Jane'), ('Joe');

CREATE TABLE dbo.Shifts
(
    ShiftID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Shifts 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , EmpID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_Shifts_EmpID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Employees(EmpID) 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
    , InDate DATE
    , ShiftStatusID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_Shifts_ShiftStatusID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.ShiftStatii(ShiftStatusID) 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Shifts (EmpID, InDate, ShiftStatusID) 
VALUES (1, '20130201', 1)
    , (2, '20130201', 2)
    , (3, '20130201', 1)
    , (1, '20130202', 1)
    , (2, '20130202', 2)
    , (3, '20130202', 1)
    , (1, '20130203', 1)
    , (2, '20130203', 1)
    , (3, '20130203', 2)
    , (1, '20130205', 1)
    , (2, '20130205', 3)
    , (3, '20130205', 2);

SELECT E.EmployeeName, S.InDate, SS.StatusName
FROM dbo.Shifts S
    INNER JOIN dbo.Employees E ON S.EmpID = E.EmpID
    INNER JOIN dbo.ShiftStatii SS ON S.ShiftStatusID = SS.ShiftStatusID
ORDER BY E.EmployeeName, S.InDate
```

The data for my test, therefore, is:

[image]

```
SELECT E.EmployeeName, S1.InDate, S2.InDate
FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY S.EmpID ORDER BY S.InDate) AS EmpRowNum, *
        FROM dbo.Shifts S) S1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY S.EmpID ORDER BY S.InDate) AS EmpRowNum, *
        FROM dbo.Shifts S
        ) S2 ON S1.EmpID = S2.EmpID AND S1.EmpRowNum = S2.EmpRowNum - 1
INNER JOIN dbo.Employees E ON S1.EmpID = E.EmpID
WHERE S1.ShiftStatusID = 2 AND S2.ShiftStatusID = 2
```

The results of this are:

[image]